# store text_field in rails separate by comma in many to many assosiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this models to store text_field in rails separate by comma in many to many assosiation.

```
class PaymentSupplier < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :folio_has_payment_suppliers
    has_many :folios, through: :folio_has_payment_suppliers, dependent: :destroy

    serialize :folio_ids, Array

    def folio_ids=(ids)
      self.folio_ids = ids.split(',')
    end
end
```

**folio_has_payment_supplier.rb**

```
class FolioHasPaymentSupplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :folio
  belongs_to :payment_supplier
end
```

**folio.rb**

```
class Folio < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :folio_has_payment_suppliers
  has_many :payment_suppliers, through: :folio_has_payment_suppliers, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And my partial form for payment_supplier#_form.html.erb my code for text_field separate by comma is

```
<%= f.text_field :folio_ids, :class => 'form-control' %>
```

When i submit my application frezee, this is my log

```
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/controllers/egr/payment_suppliers_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

Any idea please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this is because the field assignment goes into a infinite loop with self association. You can use an `attr_accessor` to get the user entered information into a Serialized (Array) column.

It would look something like this:

**PaymentSupplier**

```
class PaymentSupplier < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...

    serialize :folio_ids, Array
    attr_accessor :folio_ids_text

    def folio_ids_text=(ids)
      self.folio_ids = ids.split(",").map(&:strip) # added map(&:strip)
    end
end
```

**form**

```
<%= f.text_field :folio_ids_text, :class => 'form-control' %>
```

Make sure you account for `folio_ids_text` in strong parameters. Also, it might be a good idea to dynamically associate objects/relations, instead of having to manually enter IDs :).

Comment: Thank you, your solutions works perfectly and yeah, i'll try associate dinamically with token inputs object/relations, but first i want manually. Really i'm new in rails 6 mothns and i don't now know many things, really thank you

Comment: @UzielTrujillo Cheers. All the best! (Would be great if you can mark the answer as "Accepted" :))

Comment: @shayong i had many years reading answers in stakoverflow but this is my first question :P, tomorrow with calm, seach how i can mark the answer with Accepted i promise :P